# Logging in using @angular/fire/auth results in 403 error on localhost

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build an Angular based web application that uses the Firebase authentication with Google as authentication provider.

All the examples on the internet that I can find uses angularfire2, but when I install it, I get a warning that it is deprecated and I should now use @angular/fire.

So I build a project using @angular/fire, started the project with `ng serve`. But when I try to sign in with Google as Authentication Provider I get a 403 error that states:

> This app is not yet configured to make OAuth requests. To do that, set up the app’s OAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud Console.

Which is strange since according to the authorized domains list of the firebase console `localhost` is an authorized domain

This is what I have done so far:

- I have setup a firebase project and enabled Google in the authentication sign-in method tab of the firebase console.
- I copied the config snippet to use them for my environment.ts file
- setup an auth.service file based on @angular/fire/auth
- edited the app.module
- created a small component to give me a button that when clicked triggers the loginWithGoogle() function offered by my auth.service.

environment.ts (replaced some values in this post with '...'):

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "vkfep-422d5.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://vkfep-422d5.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "vkfep-422d5",
    storageBucket: "vkfep-422d5.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  }
};
```

auth.service.ts

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  loginWithGoogle() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    return this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  logout() {
    return this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthService } from './core/auth.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can it be that this error is caused because I hadn't set a support email adres in the firebase console project settings under the general tab?
Now that I have set an email adres the error has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could indeed be fixed by setting the support email adres within the firebase console.
Of what I'm not sure is whether this is a shortcoming in the firebase documentation or that this is an error in the angularfire library.